# View is scrolling with white background in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I have set ScrollEnabled false in config.xml but my application is scrolling in mobile device, I haven't added any scrolling properties but I have this issue. Anyone facing this issue on Iocic or am I missing something. I have attached my screenshot below.[image]

```
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
```

Comment: Ionic runs your app in a "browser", that's normal that you see scrolling bar when you run your app in a browser like chrome, firefox, etc. Try running your app on an emulator or a real device.

Comment: I don't get this issue on chrome or browser but when I run on device I get this issue @kaanyılmaz

Comment: How long or wide your screens? They might not fit on a device but fit on a browser.

Comment: I am testing on iPhone 6s plus

Comment: I meant the application screens